# How to merge multiple data frames made from a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, merge, append

I've written a loop that creates multiple data frames from one large data frame based on unique IDs so the loop ends up producing df56256, df65987 etc (where the numbers after the "df" are the unique IDs)

I wanted to know how to merge all those data frames from my loop so I can create one large frame at the end given that the large data frame will be different every time (so the multiple data sets created will have different names every time).

UPDATE

For example, I have the following large data set
Total_df:

| ID | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 27 |
| 11111 | 29 |
| 11111 | 28 |
| 11112 | 27 |
| 11112 | 30 |
| 11112 | 27 |

My loop ends up with two data frames

**df11111**:

| ID | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 11111 | 27 |
| 11111 | 29 |
| 11111 | 28 |

**df11112**

| ID | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 11112 | 27 |
| 11112 | 30 |
| 11112 | 27 |

I want to merge these data frames together at the end of my loop (or outside it). However, I won't know the names of the individual data frames every time as the IDs will change because I will be using a different "Total_df" every time.

Comment: take a look at purrr's `map_dfr`

Comment: Or could also be a case for `bind_rows`, see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html)

Comment: make yous question reproducible, with a *minimal* sample-dataset, and the desired output. beside that: IN R, you are probably better of splitting your large data.frame to a list of id's (using `split()` perhaps), and the perform actions on this single list.